# Query works in psql but Syntax error in Python with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I have a query which works well in psql, but generates an error in my program:

```
sql = 'SELECT id, x, y FROM table_name WHERE y NOT LIKE 'pa%' AND x IS NOT NULL;' 
cur.execute(sql)
```

Any pointers as to why it's not working? Or any suggestions, how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not about `PostgreSQL` vs `MySQL` query syntax - this is just syntactically wrong in Python:

```
>>> sql = 'SELECT id, x, y FROM table_name WHERE y NOT LIKE 'pa%' AND x IS NOT NULL;' 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sql = 'SELECT id, x, y FROM table_name WHERE y NOT LIKE 'pa%' AND x IS NOT NULL;' 
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Put the query into double quotes:

```
sql = "SELECT id, x, y FROM table_name WHERE y NOT LIKE 'pa%' AND x IS NOT NULL;"
```

Comment: I feel silly now, totally never thought of it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The good practice for code strings in Python is the triple quoted string which makes it much clearer and can contain both single and double quotes:

```
sql = '''
    SELECT id, x, y
    FROM table_name
    WHERE y NOT LIKE 'pa%' AND x IS NOT NULL;
'''
```

From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str):

> Triple quoted strings may span multiple lines - all associated whitespace will be included in the string literal.